# :first-child and :last-child simultaneously

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class, css-selectors

This may be very easy as i have a feeling i'm missing a basic point here.

Situation:

```
.singleOrder:first-child {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.singleOrder:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

Works really well until there is only one child. In that case the second declaration will overwrite the first one and the desired effect will not be achieved.

What is the most short and elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Split it:

```
.singleOrder:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

.singleOrder:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

Or write an extra rule:

```
.singleOrder:first-child:last-child {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: They are valid as well as your original code was. However, you should include the prefixed properties too. See [this tool](http://border-radius.com/)

Comment: Thank You. The second one works fine. I'll pick this answer because it came first.

Comment: I think the second option of adding an extra rule makes it more clear and readable

Answer (score 5):

Use `:only-child`:

```
.singleOrder:only-child {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

Update: Yogu is right. I forgot to mention. This should come after your statements.

Comment: Not sure whether this overrides the `:first-child` and `:last-child` rules. So you should make sure that this rule comes _after_ the existing two.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- <link href="sa.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
    <style>
      .try p:first-child {
        color: rgb(26, 184, 40);
      }
      .try p:last-child {
        color: red;
      }
      .try p:nth-child(2) {
        color: blue;
      }
    </style>
    <title>By using this way we can able to use any selectors using child concept</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="try">
      <p>hi</p>
      <p>buddy</p>
      <p>hru</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing supporting information for your answer, describing why this solution works